# Create different type of layout inside a list for each items based on condition flutter web

Tags: flutter

Is it possible to create the below UI in flutter using **flutter_staggered_grid_view: ^0.6.2** package.In this same list i need different type of layouts.Like if image size is large then need to show the text and images as vertical otherwise horizontal.If image is empty then show text only

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Simply add the condition before your `Tile` or after your `return` statement depending on your code:

```
if (snapshot.data![index]['image'] != null)
  Column(
    children: [
      Your tile code with image...
   ],
  ),

if (snapshot.data![index]['image'] == null)
  Column(
    children: [
      Your tile code without image...
   ],
  ),
.
.
.
```

Or use `if` shorthand

```
snapshot.data![index]['image'] != null ?
  Column(
    children: [
      Your tile code with image...
   ],
  ) :
  Column(
    children: [
      Your tile code without image...
   ],
  );
```

Comment: Thank you for your response..I know the condition but i am confusing about the widget used for listing.I checked the documentation of above package but i didnt saw these kind of ui.Because the count of each items in a row vary.Count of row is only 2 if image is placed horizontally otherwise 3

Comment: You can use the Masonry layout in the documentation: